# What is the difference between Either a and Either Int? What is Either a ? A polymorphic type constructor? What is its purpose?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, functor, type-constructor

**Introduction**:

I understand the difference between `Maybe a` and `Maybe Int`, I also understand the difference between `Either a b` and `Either Int Int`. I also understand that `Either Int` is the same kind of animal as `Maybe`, they both take a type as an argument and produce a new type i.e. they are both type constructors that take a single type as parameter (either concrete like Int or not concrete like `a`) and produce either a concrete type or polymorphic type.

Now what I don't understand is what kind of construct is `Either a` ? It is not like `Maybe` because it can never produce a concrete (read not polymorphic)  type if we feed a concrete type (like `Int`) to it. So in this case is it correct to call `Either a` a polymorphic type constructor and call `Maybe` a concrete type constructor ? ( This is just how I call them, what are their official name in the Haskell nomenclature?)

Furthermore, I don't know what is the official categorization within the Haskell type system of type constructors like `Either a` because it cannot be in the same kind of category as `Maybe` because - as mentioned in the previous paragraph - no matter to what type we apply `Either a` the resulting type never will be a concrete type, i.e. it will always be a polymorhic type, for example, `Either a Int`.

The reason why I am asking this is because `Either a` is a `Functor`. Which starts to get confusing. Nothing like anything I've seen before. I don't know how should I conceptually interpret the fact that `Either a` ( a polymorphic type constructor ) is an instance of `Functor`? Similarly, `(->) r` (which is also the same kind of animal as `Either a`) is a `Functor` too.

**Questions:**

What are `Either a` and `(->) r` ?

What are they called officially?

How do they conceptually fit into the type system of Haskell ?

Where are these polymorphic type constructors described / discussed in more detail?

What whould I read about so I get a better understanding of them?

Should I read about kinds? Are kinds the secret way towards understanding such polymorphic type constructors as `Either a` and `(->) r`?

Is `Either a Int` the same kind of animal as `[a]` ?

Is the only purpose of `Either a Int` to declare polymorphic input and output types for functions, just like in the case of `[a]` in `fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`?

**Most important question**:

How should I interpret the following code in the light of the above described thoughts?

```
instance Functor (Either a) where 
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x) 
  fmap f (Left x) = Left x

class Functor f where 
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So the resulting `fmap` function (whose type is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either c a -> Either c b`)  will be polymorphic in `c` ?

Is this the only effect of making `Either a` an instance of `Functor`? 
So that the resulting `fmap` function will be polymorphic in `c` ?

**As compared to**, for example, making `Either Int` an instance of `Functor`?

Then the resulting `fmap` would work only on `Either Int a` types but would not work generally/polymorphically on all `Either a b` types?

If I understand correctly is this the only point and purpose of having polymorphic type constructors like `Either a` ? So that `fmap` works on all `Either a b` types?

I am confused and I am not sure if I am interpreting `Either a` correctly. Could someone please comfirm that 1) either my interpretation is correct 2) if not then please enlighten me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maybe` is not a type. `Maybe Int` is a type. But `Maybe`, on its own, is something you can make a type out of. It is a *type constructor function*.

`Either` is not a type, it is a type constructor. You know how you can curry Haskell functions? Well, you can curry type constructor functions too. So `Either` is a 2-argument type constructor function, but `Either Int` is a 1-argument type constructor. And `Either Int Bool` is an actual type.

The `Functor` type-class is a *higher-kinded type-class*. Something like `Show` applies to a *type*; `Functor` applies to a *type constructor*. For example, you do not write

```
instance Functor (Maybe Int) where ...
```

Instead, you write

```
instance Functor (Maybe) where ...
```

The definition of `Functor` is

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (x -> y) -> f x -> f y
```

Here `f` is not a *type*, but a 1-argument type constructor function. You give it an argument (such as `x` or `y`) to construct a real, usable type.

Values have "types". Things in a type signature have "kinds". A "type" has kind `*`. A "1-argument type constructor" has kind "* -> *". It basically says how many arguments you have to supply to get an actual type.

In summary, you *could* write an instance for `Functor (Either Int)`. But then only `Int` would be allowed; by making it a type variable, you make it more polymorphic.

Notice that if you wanted it so that the *second* argument to `Either` was fixed rather than the first one... you can't do that. In a sense, higher-kinded type-classes are a bit of a kludge. It they're simple to understand and they work for the easy cases. Functional Dependencies and Associated Types are two (incompatible) attempts to solve this problem better.

Answer (score 11):

There's not really any such thing as `Either a`. Like polymorphic functions, polymorphic instances should be read system-F style with universal quantification:

```
forall a . instance Functor (Either a) where ...
```

The functor instance itself is a dictionary, i.e. type-level function

```
functor = Λf -> { Λa b -> (a->b) -> f a->f b }
```

So the either instance would be something like

```
eitherFunctor = Λa -> functor (Either a)
```

Alternatively you can think about it as if the compiler replaced `instance Functor (Either a)` with tons of discrete instances

```
instance Functor (Either ()) where ...
instance Functor (Either Int) where ...
...
instance Functor (Either (Either Int String)) where ...
...
```

Though it would obviously not be possible to do that, literally.

Comment: What does the symbol `Λ` mean ?

Comment: Where can I read about this(system-F style?) in more detail? What is system-F Style?  In which book is system-F style described?

Comment: What is a dictionary i.e. type level function?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a beginner in Haskell and the only part I understand from this answer is the "... as if the compiler replaced... " part. Could someone please explain the rest of the answer or point me towards some literature that I should read so that I can fully understand this answer? Many thanks.

Comment: @jhegedus, System F is not a style, it is a mathematical theory (an extension of typed lambda calculus) on which Haskell type system is based. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F

Comment: @Sibi, big lambda is a symbol from System F, it means an abstraction over types, just like small lambda is an abstraction over values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know answers to some of your questions - like, what some things are called officially, or where to read about them, because they look self-evident to me after studying type systems. (This should not be taken as a advice that the only way to get undestanding is to go study dependent type systems.)

`Either Int` can be declared a `Functor`, too, but we can express a more general statement, that it doesn't actually matter whether the first argument to `Either` is `Int` - therefore, we declare that `Either a` is a `Functor`.

In other type systems there is no need to distinguish `kinds`, instead `Either` can be treated as a type, too; but in Haskell they are treated separately from types to simplify the type system. `Kinds` are a way to describe that types have arity and avoid complications with dependent types by only distinguishing arity. So, `Either` and `(->)` have arity 2, or `kind` `*->*->*`.

`Either a Int` is the same kind of animal as `[a]` in the sense that their kind is `*`.

`fmap :: (a->b) -> Either c a -> Either c b` is polymorphic in `c`, indeed. The importance of this declaration is that it **preserves** the `c`. Of course, the only way this can happen for any type `c` is when `Left x` remains untouched.